# Why does an excel generated with POI take less time to read than one saved with MS Excel?

Tags: apache-poi

My application exports an excel with POI and when importing said excel it takes me 2 minutes, but if I modify an excel cell with MS Excel 2016 the import now takes 7 minutes.

The excel created by POI occupies 2,373 Kb and when I modify it with MS Excel 2016 it occupies 2,562 Kb.

Can someone tell me what could be the problem?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about `XSSF`, which is Apache POI's implementation of Office Open XML file format `*.xlsx`. I guess that, because for the binary file format `*.xls`, which Apache POI implements in `HSSF`, this should not happen, at least not in that intensity.

The [Open XML Formats and file name extensions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml-formats-and-file-name-extensions-5200d93c-3449-4380-8e11-31ef14555b18) got published in 2007 in first versions. And this is what Apache POI bases on. Microsoft has developed extensions to the Office Open XML file format later. Some of them got implemented in Apache POI too, but not all.

Furthermore, Apache POI stores only really necessary file system parts in it's implementations of Office Open XML file format. It omits the unimportant. For `*.xlsx` for example it omits the theme settings and the calculation chain for example. Excel will fall back to defaults when those parts are omitted. But it will store those parts in the file when Excel saves the file again.

So the short answer is: The file size differs because of additional extensions to the Office Open XML file format, which Apache POI not considers while Excel adds it into the file system when Excel saves the file. And because of additional file system parts which Apache POI not stores into the file system while Excel does.

It not only increases the file size if Excel stores additional things into the file system but also the complexity. Office Open XML file system stores XML and Apache POI parses this XML and creates appropriate Java Objects while opening the file. Thus, more XML results in more parsing overhead and more Java objects in memory.

All  Office Open XML file formats (`*.xlsx`, `*.docx`, `*.pptx`, ...) are ZIP archives. So one can unzip the files using a ZIP-archive-software (7-Zip can do this for example). Then one can have a look into the stored file system structure and determine the differences between files generated from Apache POI and files stored by Microsoft Office.

But 2 minutes to create a `XSSFWorkbook` from a `*.xlsx` file using Apache POI is much to long. This indicates that there is not enough memory available. You should give your Java more memory to use while runtime. And 7 minutes to create a `XSSFWorkbook` from a `*.xlsx` file  is beyond any tolerance. So definitely your Java needs more usable memory while runtime.